# Log all network requests initiated by PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand a codebase and it would help to know when it's accessing remote resources. Is there a way to log all outbound requests using PHP (i.e. without using a network sniffer)? I want to log all `curl_exec`, `file_get_contents`, `ftp_get`, etc.

Comment: Aside from editing the codebase and make it log every outbound request, no. Outbound traffic doesn't pass through your webserver software (Apache / NGinx etc). So you either have to use a packet sniffer or manually go through the code and create your own logs.

Comment: with a half decent IDE, it should be not too hard to find.  I use PHPStorm and ran a just ran a `find usage` on `curl_exec` on a large code base, took all of 1.5 seconds.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg if someone did `$foo = 'curl' . '_exec';$foo();`, that won't work anymore. I want a comprehensive way to find all the outbound requests.

Comment: @LeoJiang ... good point. That would probably not happen on my shift, but if I inherited a *hostile* code base, it is a possibility. I guess protocol sniffing would be my only recourse, (alongside an exhaustive test suite to exercise all nooks and crannies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all of the actual function calls in the code, you could use the [xdebug profiler](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

1. Install and enable the xdebug profiler (not on a production server).
2. Run through every feature of your application.
3. Open the profiler output file in an application (QCacheGrind, PHPStorm, etc.).
4. Search for calls to `curl_exec`, `file_get_contents`, etc.

These applications will show you file name and line number called, as well as the full stack trace that got to those calls.